Проблема cо стилями (CSS)
Всем привет. Пишу документацию - Когда есть картинка название и Описание съезжает в лево. Помогите справить
CSS:
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    color: #333;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 30px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
}

.logo img {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
}

.logo-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-item img {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.content-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 80px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 30px;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

.character {
    width: 425px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: -200px;
}

.text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 400px);
    margin-left: 400px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #555;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.invite {
    background-color: #6a0dad;
}

.more-info {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.features {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 400px;
}

.features h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature-boxes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 30px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.feature-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.feature-box .icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.feature-box .icon img {
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
}

.feature-box .text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}

.feature-box h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.feature-box p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Milony</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap"> <!-- Подключаем шрифт -->
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
                <span class="logo-text">Milony</span>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item">
                    <img src="docslogo.png" alt="Docs Logo"> 
                    Документация
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item">
                    <img src="lovelogo.png" alt="Milony Plus Logo">
                    Milony Plus
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="content-box">
        <img src="character.png" alt="Character" class="character">
        <div class="text-content">
            <h1>Раскройте потенциал вашего сервера</h1>
            <p>Универсальный бот с множеством функций для повышения эффективности и улучшения вашего сообщества в Discord.</p>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="#" class="btn invite">Пригласить</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn more-info">Подробнее</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="features">
        <h2>Что умеет Milony?</h2>
        <div class="feature-boxes">
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="MusicLogo.png" alt="Music Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="text-content">
                    <h3>Музыка</h3>
                    <p>Наслаждайтесь любимыми мелодиями прямо в вашем Discord-сообществе, ищите песни и создавайте идеальное музыкальное сопровождение для любых событий.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="ModeratorLogo.png" alt="Moderator Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="text-content">
                    <h3>Модерация</h3>
                    <p>Обеспечьте порядок и безопасность вашего сообщества с инструментами модерации, настраивайте автоматические фильтры и предотвращайте нежелательное поведение.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="ChatNeuroLogo.png" alt="Chat Neuro Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="text-content">
                    <h3>Нейросеть</h3>
                    <p>Поддерживайте активное общение с участниками благодаря чат-боту на базе ИИ. Он ответит на любые вопросы и поддержит дружескую атмосферу в чате.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="feature-box">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="MiniGamesLogo.png" alt="Mini Games Logo">
                </div>
                <div class="text-content">
                    <h3>Мини-игры</h3>
                    <p>Развлекайте участников с увлекательными мини-играми, играйте в крестики-нолики и змейку, добавляя веселье и разнообразие в ваш Discord-чат.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>



body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    color: #333;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #0d0d0d;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header-content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 30px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;
}

.logo img {
    width: 60px;
    height: auto;
}

.logo-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
}

.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-item img {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.content-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 80px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 300px;
    align-items: center; /* Выравнивание изображения и текста по центру */
}

.character {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}

.text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px;
    flex: 1; /* Распределение оставшегося места между изображением и текстом */
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #555;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buttons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.invite {
    background-color: #6a0dad;
}

.more-info {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.features {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 400px;
}

.features h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.feature-boxes {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 30px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.feature-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.feature-box .icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.feature-box .icon img {
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
}

.feature-box .text-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1;
}

.feature-box h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.feature-box p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

попробуй

Спасибо, помогло
